# Setting property doesn't work

Tags: c#

I have a class Banner

```
public class Banner
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public virtual string TextField { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

and somewhere in my code i have a method to change the value of Disabled.

```
public void ToggleEnableDisable(int Id)
{
    Banner banner = _session.Query<Banner>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);

    if (banner != null && banner.Disabled)
    {
        banner = banner.Disabled = false //This isn't working, i get cannot convert source type to target type
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: why would you set `banner` to false? banner is a `Banner` instance not a bool

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in future - look at the preview of the post before you hit submit, and ask yourself if that's what you'd want to see if you were trying to answer the question.

Comment: **replace** banner = banner.Disabled = false **by** banner.Disabled = false;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the fact that you're setting the property - it's that you're trying to use the *result* of setting the property as the input for setting `banner` itself. You just want:

```
banner.Disabled = false;
```

Comment: A small note for the OP: Since the method is called `Toggle...` It might be better to just do `banner.Disabled = !banner.Disabled`